# Magento error in admin - Payment method does not exist

Tags: magento

I had been using a custom payment module that I had built from scratch to accept payments from a particular gateway company. However, the company has recently uploaded a better magento extension that i have now uploaded.

However, since I also cleared the old files for clarity the order details page no longer opens generating an error that the payment method does not exist.

I am guessing that for each order, Magento would store the payment method in the database. If I can get hold of that attribute and change all old values to the new value id - this error would be taken care of.

I have looked in the sales_flat_order and many other tables but cannot figure out where this value is stored. Can anyone point the actual table and attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This is stored in the `method` column of the `sales_flat_quote_payment` and `sales_flat_order_payment` tables.

Comment: Thanks. Would replacing the field of any particular tuple ensure that the payment method change is reflected anywhere?

Comment: Yes, however, please be aware that if you have another extension expecting any specific information coming back from the payment type you change it to, you could have issues.  So, if you change it to the new payment type and it expects field xyz to be able to render in admin, and it isn't there...